# Add data from an array using its value for key to another Array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

Hi i have two Arrays one being Parsed Data that has multiple entries at each cell (FolderName & ID) i want this data to be saved into another array like it is stored in the first array

```
   FilteredData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[ParsedData ValueForKey:@"FolderName"]];

   SearchData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:FilteredData];
```

This is what i have been trying, The data Containing a dictionary at each entry is ParsedData, And the Array in which i have to copy these items is SearchData.

The Array (Parsed Data) Containing the dictionary looks like this

```
 PARSED DATA (
    {
    CreatedBy = 1;
    FolderName = Posteingang;
    ID = 13000;
    ParentID = 0;
},
    {
    CreatedBy = 1;
    FolderName = Freigaben;
    ID = 13001;
    ParentID = 0;
},
```

From this Array I need to Get the FolderName And the ID and get them in the SearchData Array

```
SearchData (
    Posteingang;
    13000;     
    Freigaben;
    13001;
)
```

I hope the question is clear now

[image]

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: this is just copying the foldername to the array whereas i need the ID as well

Comment: An array can contain one value either folderName or ID. If you need both the values you need nested array or dictionary or even a custom class. In worst use stringWithFormat and append both of them. now tell what you want ?

Comment: I want a dictionary inside an array which contains foldername and id

Comment: Question was not clear?

Comment: @Sunny I hope now it is clear

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I have added an image showing the error in the code u posted

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I dont know if i am asking the correct question or not because this doesnt seem to work Please check my edited question can i get my data to display like that?

Comment: your question is OK. You only need to extract few KV pairs from the dictionary and create a new array from it. that is what i did in my answer. I dont have mac with me, so i cant check for compiler error. you do and tell me..

Comment: ParsedData is an array which has a dictionary at each cell value

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i have added the snippet of the error

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Check the error after i have made all the necessary changes

Comment: @RANA: check my update, there is typo... **V**alueForKey v should be small

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I have sent you the code, and after changing the "V" to "v" I still have the Following Warning +withObjectsAndKeys: Not found

Comment: for(NSDictionary *dict in ParsedData){
            NSDictionary *tempDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dict objectForKey:@"FolderName"], @"FolderName",[dict objectForKey:@"ID"],@"ID", nil];
            [SearchData addObject:tempDict];
        }

Comment: NSDictionary *tempDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[dict valueForKey:@"FolderName"], @"FolderName",[dict valueForKey:@"ID"],@"ID", nil];
            [searchData addObject:tempDict];

Comment: This is how it worked it required to be allocated and the init was missing but thanks a lot for your help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29288/discussion-between-rana-and-anoop-vaidya)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want a dictionary inside an array which contains foldername and id

So you can get it using this:

```
NSMutableArray *searchData = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSDictionary *dict in parsedDataArray){
    NSDictionary *tempDict=@{@"FolderName":dict[@"FolderName"], 
                             @"ID":dict[@"ID"]};
    [searchData addObject:tempDict];
}
```

EDIT:

`@[@"key:@"object"]` is the new dictionary literal.

If you are using Xcode 4.3 or older need to do as:

```
NSDictionary *tempDict=@{@"FolderName":dict[@"FolderName"], 
                                 @"ID":dict[@"ID"]};
```

means,

```
NSDictionary *tempDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dict objectForKey:@"FolderName"], @"FolderName",[dict objectForKey:@"ID"],@"ID", nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

check this one,

```
NSMutableArray *searchData = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in ParsedDataArray){//here ParsedDataArray  means PARSED DATA array name
        NSDictionary *tempDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[dict ValueForKey:@"FolderName"],@"FolderName",[dict ValueForKey:@"ID"],@"ID" nil], 

        [searchData addObject:dict];
    }
```

Comment: @RANA:check this one may be it'l helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you misspelled the method name, it should be:

```
dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
```

Notice the "s" after Object.